# Intellij IdeaVim: access IDE shortcuts without making vim give up control of that shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

ctrl-O is used to jump to the previous entry in the jump list.
But in the IDE, according to the documentation, ctrl-O helps you override methods declared in a base class, kind of like ctrl-enter in Eclipse when the cursor is on an empty line.

One can change a setting that will assign the control of ctrl-O to the IDE. That would make vim loose access to that key, and you'd no longer can use it to jump around the jump list.

Is there a special shortcut key, so that the next key is handled by the IDE instead of vim?

Comment: Oh yeah, like <kbd>Insert</kbd> in Vimperator. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can assign another shortcut to the override methods action via Settings | Keymap while keeping CTRL-O under control of IdeaVim in Settings | Vim Emulation.